# How to add sentence embeddings derived from an existing column into a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, sentence-transformers

I have a dataframe that has four nw_data=['Qn_id', 'Qn_context', 'Qns', 'Anwsers']. This is how it looks like

```
Qn_id  |     Qn_context       |   Qns        |     Anwsers
 01    | In 1962, Uk gave...  | what year....| the year 1962 was.....
 02    | Major kanuti raised..| Who raised...| Kanuti akorimo rasied.
```

I want to add a fifth column to that dataset that consists of the **sentence embeddings** of the column['Answers'].

Am using the sentence_transformers to generate the sentence embeddings.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
```

I tried using an approach where:

```
#Created a var for the column
sent = nw_data['Answers']
```

and

```
#Passed the variable sent into the model and created the embeddings
embeddings = model.encode(sent)
```

then

```
#Tried passing the embeddings into a new column named Embeddings
nw_data['Embeddings'] = embeddings
```

I get an error:

```
KeyError: 'Embeddings'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: 'Embeddings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in check_ndim(values, placement, ndim)
   1978         if len(placement) != len(values):
   1979             raise ValueError(
-> 1980                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(values)}, "
   1981                 f"placement implies {len(placement)}"
   1982             )

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 384, placement implies 1
```

How can i create these embeddings and add them to a new column in the same dataframe nw_data!!

Is it possible anyway, was advised try using the **.apply() method** or **lambda functions** but the issues is am not sure on how or when to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to insert a list (embedding) into a cell.

Try using [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
>>> sentences = 'Absence of sanity'
>>> embedding = model.encode(sentences)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2], 'Embedding': None})
>>> df.at[0, 'Embedding'] = embedding.tolist()
>>> df.dtypes
foo           int64
Embedding    object
>>> df.head()
dtype: object
   foo                                          Embedding
0    1  [0.2954030930995941, 0.29181134700775146, 2.16...
1    2                                               None
```

If you have multiple sentences, just pass the list:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> sentences = ['Absence of sanity', 'its a new day', 'make the best of it']
>>> embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'Embedding': None})
>>> df['Embedding'] = embeddings.tolist()
>>> print(df.head())
   foo                                          Embedding
0    1  [0.29540303349494934, 0.29181137681007385, 2.1...
1    2  [0.0362740121781826, -0.8035800457000732, 2.44...
2    3  [-0.4539063572883606, -0.4333038330078125, 2.2...
```

Comment: Yes its a list but has many sentences seperated by , example

Comment: sentences = ['Absence of sanity', 'its a new day', 'make the best of it']  So how do i perform the sentence embeddings for each sentence and then add the sentence embeddings to a dataframe column one sentence embedding per row. Keeping in mind the data frame already has its own other columns.

Comment: @andy check out my answer, you just need to add the `.tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do this, pls tell me if it works:

```
def embed_text(sentence):
       return model.encode(sentence)
nw_data['Embeddings'] = nw_data['Answers'].apply(embed_text)
```